# Julia: Diagonal times Sparse Matrix

Tags: julia, sparse-matrix, diagonal

```
A = sparse([4 0 0; 0 0 0; 4 0 0])
D = Diagonal([1;3;4])
D*A
```

Gives the error that there is no method * for performing this operation. Is there a simple way for performing the operation?

Comment: This is fixed in the development version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With convert:

```
julia> convert(SparseMatrixCSC{Int64,Int64},D)*A
3x3 sparse matrix with 2 Int64 entries:
    [1, 1]  =  4
    [3, 1]  =  16
```

General solution, from the error message:

```
julia> f(a,b)
ERROR: MethodError: `f` has no method matching f(::T1, ::T2)
```

Do:

```
julia> f(convert(T2,a),b)
```

Comment: Is there disadvantage/overhead to using a sparse matrix for a diagonal matrix?

Comment: Surely yes, but until there are better options it's the best workaround. https://github.com/timholy/ArrayIteration.jl aims to make this unnecessary, allowing one to write generic methods that handle any type of sparse-like array.